# can exceptional circumstances invalidate one article?

Tags: england-and-wales, education

I am in the UK - England. I am complaining against my University for having been misadvised in a moment of strong distress and psychological fragility - which is caused by the misbehavior of my University.

The University points to the fact that one article of the Code of Practice states that the responsibility of what has happened is by default on the shoulders of the student, independently on the circumstances. They say this basically: "this is what is written in the article, we don't take into consideration the situation you were in".

My question to you is very general, but I need it to start asking myself the right questions:

- can exceptional circumstances invalidate one article of a regulation?

---

Basically the article in question says:
"[PGRs are responsible for] Deciding when to submit their thesis (after the minimum period of study and before the end of the maximum period of study specified in Regulations), taking due account of the supervisor’s opinion which is only advisory."

---

What has happened is that, as my Primary Supervisor was neither replying to my emails nor reading my PhD thesis at all, 10 days before submitting by my proposed submission date (accepted by my supervisor) I was in panic and confused, and I wrote to my Academic Advisor (also Dean of the Department) to understand what to do in this situation. The Academic Advisor responded: "What you have to do is to submit by your deadline!!".

The university has accepted that thesis' feedback was strongly delayed (breach of another article), monitoring has fallen below standard (breach of another article), I submitted many complaints during my PhD time about problems of miscommunication with professors (without anybody addressing the issue), that an issue that I rose 3 months before submitting was a concern that came out during my viva (though not substantial), and that the reply of my Academic Advisor was ambiguous, but they say that the article says that I have to take responsibility on my choice to submit by that date (or, that I have to take responsibility on the act of submitting) - as that was not my maximum submission date.

The fact is that I was in panic and afraid to raise a complaint against my supervisor because of power relations (reference for a future job), as I do believe that the above makes the situation I was in very extraordinary. Not knowing what to do, my Academic Advisor (and Dean of the Department) instead of investigating the situation and proposing me various options on how to solve the situation, suggested to me to submit my thesis.

Comment: You might want to edit your question so as to reflect more precisely the language of that article. A *default presumption* can in many contexts be refuted or stricken on the basis of evidence that contradicts it. In the alternative, "default" could have a connotation of "indisputable". It is impossible to ascertain which sense applies here without first knowing the exact language of that article and possibly other relevant portions of the Code of Practice.

Comment: Thank you @IñakiViggers, is the above description helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I gather that your actual question is whether (1) the article compels the student to commit to his announced date for submission of thesis, or (2) submission can be rescheduled (subject to the hard deadline of "*end of the maximum period of study*"). The language of the excerpt you reproduce suggests that rescheduling *is* an option, since it is only in terms of "*submitting*" a thesis. The language does not reflect that the student's *previously announced date* is final or a *firm deadline*.

Thus, the university's interpretation

> that the article says that I have to take responsibility on my choice
>   to submit by that date

improperly creates a constraint, unless by "that date" the university means "*the end of the maximum period of study*".

Since you indicate that

> that was not my maximum submission date

there is no need to seek invalidation of that article this time.

Also, applying the language of the article, I would conclude that the Academic Advisor's suggestion [that you submit your thesis sooner] *is only advisory*. Without knowing about PhD or academic policies, I see no reason why an advisor's opinion should be mandatory or supersede a supervisor's advisory opinion.

The question of whether the university's series of breaches entitles you to an exemption from that article is more complex and would require additional information. Moreover, the conclusions therefrom would be uncertain because of discretionary factors about which it would be pointless to speculate.

Comment: So I guess the answer is "yes, it could be, but maybe this is not the case", right? My point is that I was in panic due to my main reference that was not providing his service of support and supervision, and on the other side I had a deadline, and I was not put in the condition to make an independent decision due to the extraordinary circumstances. If that was the case, the independence of decision-making of the student might be polluted by the ambiguous suggestion of the Academic Advisor (the university has recognized that the suggestion is formulated in ambiguous terms). Am I correct?

Comment: The Academic Advisor didn't suggest to submit sooner. He suggested to respect my deadline (agreed with my supervisor) regardless of the concern I rose, on which I had no control (my supervisor was not reading my thesis and I was afraid of my lack of supervision in such a decisive moment).

Comment: Also, may I ask you to expand a little your last sentence? I don't understand whether you say it's pointless to speculate here, or in general.

Comment: @LucaDanieli By "*sooner*" I meant anything prior to "*the end of the maximum period of study*", since that is the latest deadline the article permits. Since the supervisor's opinion is *only advisory* (see language in the article), you are entitled to postpone the submission of your thesis to until "the end of the maximum period of study". As for "pointless to speculate", I meant that some articles might give professors/deans/etc. discretion on *how* or *when* to weigh factors for deciding whether or not to grant exemptions from that article.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I could postpone the submission of my thesis. Thing is: if my supervisor is not doing his job, not supervising me and not responding, should I keep postponing? I agreed with my supervisor about a deadline, and I thought I should respect that deadline. At least, I'd like to discuss about postponing and making a new schedule. Still that is not the point: I asked my Academic Advisor (and Dean of the Department) about the best way to protect myself in that confusing situation, and presented with only one option and been encouraged to submit. This is not advisory.

Comment: As per the article, there is a limit to how long you can keep postponing, and both advisor and dean are being incompetent by not addressing the core issue you are experiencing: the supervisor's pattern of negligence. Other than interpreting the article (which I gathered was what you were asking) I don't know what to suggest because I have no idea about your university's remedies.(The initial supervisor of my thesis was also negligent. Like you, I was afraid of retaliation if I reported him. Luckily he eventually got fired and I was assigned a diligent one with whom I graduated 3 months later).

Comment: Your story is amazing! Thanks for sharing it!
Well, I just wanted to know if the article was super strict. I am going to apply to the OIA, and am understanding how to prepare my argument.

Comment: I have found the thing finally, I guess! Months to understand it: I sought advice to protect my rights and solve the extraordinary circumstances that were out of my control and were affecting my Ph.D. In this situation, the only option I was proposed was to submit my thesis by my deadline and wait for the response of my examiners. Given the lack of other options, and the delicate position of the student in such a situation, I could do nothing but submit.

Comment: On top, the emphatic tone of the Academic Advisor gave me the belief that submitting was the right procedure to protect my rights in sight of any future problem. The article mentioned above can't be valid in this case for the reason that the act of submitting is not strictly academic-related in nature, but is mixed to a sense of protection against the same problems I have incurred by submitting and that the university has failed to address timely. Does it make sense?

Comment: @LucaDanieli "*the emphatic tone of the Academic Advisor gave me the belief that submitting was the right procedure to protect my rights in sight of any future problem*". I would not count on that. And I do **not** want to lead you to believe that the examiners would be lenient on this (or even bother to ascertain the difficult circumstances) because the article is clear: "*the supervisor's opinion is only advisory*". Hence, your reliance on the advisor's emphatic tone is very unlikely to matter to them.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I think you are right that I should stay on facts, rather than interpretations. However, am I right if I say that the term "advisory" in the article above is strictly related to the matter of "quality" of my submission, and that any advice outside that scope falls outside? I guess there is something wrong if I ask my Academic Advisor an opinion on the right procedure to resolve a concern, and he suggests me first to submit and then to rise my concern to the Head of School (and this one tells me he can't do anything). The opposite should have happened.

Comment: @LucaDanieli The article does not qualify or limit the meaning of "advisory" to "quality" of the submission. Otherwise it would fall in the category of *leniency*, which I ruled out in my [previous comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36404/can-exceptional-circumstances-invalidate-one-article/36410?noredirect=1#comment65521_36410). The article is only about *deadlines* for submission of a thesis, whence it would be wrong to interpret that article as a provision regarding "quality".